# How to modify SOAP body in JBoss 6

Tags: web-services, jboss6.x

I'm trying to modify SOAP body for an outbound ws client SOAP message, from an application which is deployed on JBoss 6.1.0. Final.
There is a registered HandlerResolver for that purpose, which has the following code:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messagecontext) {
        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) messagecontext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outbound) {
            try {
                SOAPMessage soapMessage = messagecontext.getMessage();
                SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

                Node firstChild = soapBody.getFirstChild();

                String timeStamp = getTimestamp();
                String signature = getSignature(firstChild.getLocalName(), timeStamp, secretBytes);

                SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPElement signatureElement = factory.createElement("Signature");
                System.out.println(signature);
                signatureElement.addTextNode(signature);

                SOAPElement timestampElement = factory.createElement("Timestamp");
                timestampElement.addTextNode(timeStamp);

                firstChild.appendChild(signatureElement);
                firstChild.appendChild(timestampElement);                   

            } catch(SOAPException se) {
                throw new RuntimeException("SOAPException was thrown.", se);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, it throws this exception:

```
17:59:35,527 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker] HANDLER_RAISED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
```

for this line:

```
firstChild.appendChild(signatureElement);
```

This code worked fine with JBoss 5.1.0.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between Axis(used in JBoss 5.1) and Cxf(used in JBoss 6.1.0 as default) frameworks creates this problem. That's why this code worked fine with JBoss 5.1.0.

Here is the [solution](https://community.jboss.org/message/714363).